# Parse XML using PHP with multiple namespaces

Tags: php, xml, soap, cisco-axl

I have an xml file which i am having a hard time to correctly parse:
I need to retrieve the Value from the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ns1:PerfmonCollectCounterDataResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/">
                <ArrayOfCounterInfo soapenc:arrayType="ns1:CounterInfoType[2]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:CounterInfoType">
                        <Name xsi:type="ns1:CounterNameType">\\172.16.106.18\Number of Replicates Created and State of Replication(ReplicateCount)\Number of Replicates Created</Name>
                        <Value xsi:type="xsd:long">603</Value>
                        <CStatus xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">1</CStatus>
                    </item>
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:CounterInfoType">
                        <Name xsi:type="ns1:CounterNameType">\\172.16.106.18\Number of Replicates Created and State of Replication(ReplicateCount)\Replicate_State</Name>
                        <Value xsi:type="xsd:long">2</Value>
                        <CStatus xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">1</CStatus>
                    </item>
                </ArrayOfCounterInfo>
            </ns1:PerfmonCollectCounterDataResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the code that I am running:

```
// fclose($fopen);
// if (file_exists($filename)) {    
    // $output = simplexml_load_file($filename,null,null,"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",true);  // I have also tried without the namespaces
    ;
    //$output = simplexml_load_string($xmldata);

    //var_dump($output);
    //print_r($output);     
} else {
    echo "File not found";
}
```

Below is the empty object I am getting:

```
object (SimpleXMLElement)[3]
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

That actually is not an empty object, and has methods against it. This is expected. If you did

```
echo $output->asXML();
```

You will see your XML string returned.

Now perform methods against this to iterate the data set and retrieve your specific values.

Also, if you're dealing with debugging simplexml frequently, [consider this function](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug)

Comment: Thanks for the update the fuction simplexml_tree() looks ffod. I will explore it. I have used "asXML" and it is returning the values of the entire XML. I was using                                                           echo $output->Body->PerfmonCollectCounterDataResponse->ArrayOfCounterInfo[1]->item->Value .... and I get the error Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\axl.php .           Pls let me know what seems to be the error here. I am new to XML parsing

Comment: @RAVI SOAP requires it's own NS to be passed to the `->children()` method

Comment: I have been banging my head around this but still unable to traverse it. Either I an getting a null value or something like "Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__toString(): Node no longer exists in". any suggestions??